# How to migrate shutoff instance to specific host?

Tags: migration, openstack

I use OpenStack Icehouse and would like to migrate shutoff instances to specific hosts. For nova live migration, we can assign the host when migrating, but it only works for active instances. How about shutoff instances? For `nove migrate` API, the host is determined by nova-scheduler. How do I migrate shutoff instances to specific host? Thanks.

Comment: You have to use the `nova migrate` command. Check the API Reference [here](http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/content/novaclient_commands.html#novaclient_subcommand_migrate)

Comment: Yes. I know I should use nova migrate command, BUT this command **CANNOT assign a target host**. How should I migrate a shutoff instance and ASSIGN a target host for it at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: You are right, I misread your question.  I am not aware for any way to do it.